# Compare two txt files and print the difference line by line in txt file

Tags: python, windows, scripting, diff

I have two tab-delimited .txt files, and I want to compare them to each other. The end goal is to print the difference in a another .txt file, which will have only the lines where the different data in column occurs. Is it possible to do this with some script in Winodws?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write a script for this manually, although it would be relatively easy to do in e.g. Python. You can install [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) to get Linux style diff tools. You can then say (in a shell):

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

WinMerge could possibly work for you.  It has a command line interface, if you're looking to automate it.  You can check the manual at http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html.  Hope this helps!